# retrieve the smsstatus after sending sms Twilio api

Tags: twilio

i m using Twilio sms api to send message form my Asp.Net application

```
 var delivery = twilioRestClient.SendSmsMessage("+123456", mobilenumber, 
string.Format("Your New Password is: {0}", genpass));
```

the variable `delivery` contains object of twiliosendsms which also contain sms status currently the status is 'queued' when the message was sent i want to know how to check if the status is changed to `Sending,sent,failed,received`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can use the [StatusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms#post-parameters-optional) to have Twilio tell you when your message was sent.

Hope that helps.

Comment: when the message is sent from my application i receive StatusCallback with sid and status = queued 
now after message is send how can i know weather the status is changed to sent or failed

Comment: this is what i m searching for
This link will tell the status of message sent
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[accountsid]/SMS/Messages/[sid].json

But i want to get that status in my application if i provide that link to user it will ask for accountsid and auth key
which i do not provide to them

Plz tell me is there any way to get the reponse to my app without entering the API authentication details

Comment: There is no way to use the Twilio API without using your credentials.  Instead of providing the direct Twilio URL to the message, you could write an app that proxies the data to them, allowing you to make the call to Twilio using your credentials but still hiding them from the user.

Comment: Devin I have experience strange issue when using SendSmsMessage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467402/twilio-callbackurl-called-with-sendmessage-method-but-not-with-sendsmsmessage-me Callbackurl for delivery is working with SendMessage but not with SendSmsMessage