# twilio callbackurl called with SendMessage method but not with SendSmsMessage method

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio paid account for sending sms messaging.
I have also configured a callback to do some status update in my application when message is delivered to client. One odd behavior i am having is that when I am sending message with SendSmsMessage (as it is a simple sms message)  then though message is delivered to the mobile but callbackurl is not called but when I am sending me message with SendMessage method Callbackurl is working fine and status also changed to delivered on twilio dashboard.
My code is

```
  string AccountSid = "************************";
                string AuthToken = "**********************************";
                var twilioClient = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
                var twiliopaidnumber = "+15334455923";
                var message = twilioClient.SendSmsMessage(twiliopaidnumber , "+923338432293", " TestMesage ", "http://mytestcallback/TwilioResponseHandler.ashx");
                //var message = twilioClient.SendMessage(twiliopaidnumber , "+923338432293", " TestMesage ", "http://mytestcallback/TwilioResponseHandler.ashx");
```

Does anybody also have experience this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. The [SMS endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms) is deprecated in the API and doesn't respond the same way as newer resources. The `SendSmsMessage` method you are calling is using that old endpoint and `SendMessage` is using the new [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) which behaves as you're expecting.

I recommend using `SendMessage` everywhere that you need message sending.

Comment: Ok.
There should be some sort of Deprecated/ obselete attribute on SendSmsMessage

Comment: So It mean's it's the problem of SendSmsMessage internal working which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

SendMessage is the newer API call, I went thru this exact issue a few weeks ago, complicated by a few bugs :) -- [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014019/twilio-sendsmsmessage-with-callbackurl-not-working/29022894#29022894)