# How to configure Twilio send sms with callback url?

Tags: twilio, webhooks, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-functions

We have a requirement to configure callback URL with a custom parameter.
It's possible to configure the callback http url in Twilio console. 
But we have to configure the callback url when we send sms so that when the user replies, twilio will make a call to the specified url mentioned.
Is there any way to configure the callback url programmatically?

Your timely help is much appreciated.

Comment: @philnash: Could you please help

Comment: @NickNguyen Can you please help

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-properties

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348307/is-it-possible-to-change-the-messaging-url-callback-with-the-twilio-api/46351677#46351677

Comment: Thank you @MeganSpeir. i am looking for something like this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467402/twilio-callbackurl-called-with-sendmessage-method-but-not-with-sendsmsmessage-me?rq=1 I need to configure smsurl while sending sms instead of configuring while creating sender number.

Comment: Thank you @AlexBaban. I have to send a message to a phonenumber. when they reply back it has to redirect to a link with custom parameter like "https://stackoverflow.com/questions?id=256"  where id is different for each receiver. Basically, I need to configure a callback url along with custom parameter as a query string while sending the sms so that when they reply, it will redirect to its corresponding url. Could you please suggest any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't configure the SMS URL to be different based on different users responding to a Twilio number.

You can, however, direct this within your own system. [When Twilio makes the webhook to your application it sends through a bunch of parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) including `From`, the number that sent you the message.

[These parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters) are sent as URL encoded parameters in the body of the POST request.

In your application you should be able to use that `From` parameter to look up your user and then deal with the incoming message for that user.

Let me know if that helps at all.