# Is it possible to change the Messaging URL callback with the Twilio API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Hello and thank you for reading. Is it possible to change the Messaging URL callback with the Twilio API?

Comment: Are you talking about the webhook URL that is configured in console for a number for messaging when a message comes in?

Comment: yessir, thats what i'm talking about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `POST` to an `IncomingPhoneNumber` instance resource.

You can do it with `curl`, or if you're using another language read these docs,
 https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers?code-sample=code-update-an-incomingphonenumber&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json (and select another language for the sample code).

You will need to know:

`SUB-ACCOUNT-SID` \\ the sid for the account where the phone number belongs to
`PHONE-NUMBER-SID` \\ the sid of the phone number you want to change the URL
`MASTER-ACCOUNT-SID` \\ your Twilio master account sid
`MASTER-ACCOUNT-TOKEN` \\ your Twilio master account token

If you're not using sub-accounts `SUB-ACCOUNT-SID` and `MASTER-ACCOUNT-SID` are the same thing.

---

***The command*** to change the URL to `http://demo.twilio.com/docs/sms.xml` (replace with your values):

```
curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/SUB-ACCOUNT-SID/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PHONE-NUMBER-SID.json -d "SmsUrl=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/sms.xml" -u "MASTER-ACCOUNT-SID:MASTER-ACCOUNT-TOKEN"
```

*Note:* when you replace the values it looks something like this

```
curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC0123456789abcdefabcdefabcdefabcd/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PN0123456789abcdefabcdefabcdefabcd.json -d "SmsUrl=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/sms.xml" -u "ACabcdefabcdefabcdefabcd0123456789:0123456789abcdefabcdefabcdefabcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using the twilio api

```js
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.incomingPhoneNumbers('PN2a0747eba6abf96b7e3c3ff0b4530f6e')
  .update({
     accountSid: 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     smsUrl: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/sms.xml',
     voiceUrl: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml'
   })
  .then(incoming_phone_number => console.log(incoming_phone_number.friendlyName))
  .done();
```